# highcharts add plotline label with images

Tags: highcharts

Using Highchart.js

is it possible to add an image to a plotline label? Something as shown below

[image]

I want to add this (i) image along with a tooltip, but it seems (from [here](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#yAxis.plotLines.label.text)) that the limited set of html available for this elements does not support images, divs, or titles.

I've figured that it would be easier to add this image and tooltip on a separated div (from graph), find the position of the label and use absolute positioning to add this layer. But I can't add any id or something to this element, so I can't find its position.

Has someone had similar issues?

**My Solution:**

**CSS**

```
.infoMedia {
    position: absolute;
    z-index : 10000;
    width: 30px;
    height: 30px;
    background: url('../img/information.png') center no-repeat;
}
```

**HTML**

```
<div class='infoMedia' style='left:0px;top:0px;'></div>
```

**javascript**

```
function processHintPosition() // every resize, call this function
{
   $('.infoMediaENEM').css('top', 0);
        $('.infoMedia').css('left', 0);

        var this_container =  $('#container_line_graph'); 

        var this_container_width = $(this_container).width();
        var this_container_height = $(this_container).height();

        var this_margin_y = 60;
        var this_margin_x = 15;


        $('.infoMedia').css('top', $(this_container).offset().top + $(this_container).height() - this_margin_y);

        // POSITION X
        var x_val = $(this_container).offset().left + this_container_width - this_margin_x; 
        $('.infoMedia').css('left', x_val)

        // POSITION Y
        var this_media = parseFloat(lineGraph.linechart_data.prcMedia);
        var this_max = 100;

        var this_val_posy = Math.ceil( ( this_media * (this_container_height - this_margin_y) ) / this_max );

        var y_val = (($('.infoMedia').offset().top) - this_val_posy) - ($('.infoMedia').height()/2);
        $('.infoMedia').css('top', y_val);
}
```

Comment: Could you possible show me how you added a label to your plotline? Thanks!

Comment: I ended up placing the icon independent from the graphics, with absolute positioning, with logic when the user scrolls or updates position.

Comment: How did you compute the position of your image ? Can you post your final solution here plz ?

Comment: You can use http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#Axis.toPixels() function

Answer (score 1):

It looks like there is a `useHTML` option for the `yAxis` `labels` configuration that allows the use of images.

http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#yAxis.labels.useHTML

Comment: yes, there is. Unfortunately, it is available for yAxis label, not for yAxis->plotLines-> label :(

Comment: @jose I realized, after posting my answer, that you were referring to the `yAxis.plotLines.labels` and not `yAxis.labels`.  All apologies.  It looks like the only options for the `plotLines.labels` are basic CSS rules (not including the `background-image` property).

Answer (score 1):

If you want to get at that element and modify it further, you can:

1.) Get it through the chart object:

```
chart.yAxis[0].plotLinesAndBands[0];
```

2.) Or, find it in the DOM by the text itself:

```
$('#container text:contains("Plot line")') // where container is the ID of the div container and "Plot line" is the text of the plot line
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also use renderer and add image in any position:

http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#Renderer.image()

Answer (score 0):

Here's an example using an inline svg.

```js
const labelConfig = {
  text: `<svg viewBox="0 0 24 24" class="plot-line-icon"><path d="M21.8 16V14.5C21.8 13.1 20.4 12 19 12S16.2 13.1 16.2 14.5V16C15.6 16 15 16.6 15 17.2V20.7C15 21.4 15.6 22 16.2 22H21.7C22.4 22 23 21.4 23 20.8V17.3C23 16.6 22.4 16 21.8 16M20.5 16H17.5V14.5C17.5 13.7 18.2 13.2 19 13.2S20.5 13.7 20.5 14.5V16M5 3C3.9 3 3 3.9 3 5V19C3 20.11 3.9 21 5 21H13.03C13 20.9 13 20.8 13 20.7V19H5V5H19V10C19.69 10 20.37 10.16 21 10.42V5C21 3.9 20.11 3 19 3H5M13.96 12.29L11.21 15.83L9.25 13.47L6.5 17H13C13.08 16.14 13.46 15.46 13.96 14.96C14.03 14.89 14.13 14.85 14.2 14.79V14.5C14.2 13.95 14.3 13.44 14.47 12.97L13.96 12.29Z"></path></svg>`,
  align: 'center',
  textAlign: 'center',
  rotation: 0,
  useHTML: true,
  x: 0,
  y: -12,
}

Highcharts.AST.allowedAttributes.push('viewBox');

Highcharts.chart('container', {
  xAxis: {
    categories: ['Jan', 'Feb', 'Mar', 'Apr', 'May', 'Jun', 'Jul', 'Aug', 'Sep', 'Oct', 'Nov', 'Dec'],
    plotLines: [{
      color: '#FF0000',
      width: 2,
      value: 2.5,
      label: labelConfig
    }]
  },

  series: [{
    data: [29.9, 71.5, 106.4, 129.2, 144.0, 176.0, 135.6, 148.5, 216.4, 194.1, 95.6, 54.4]
  }]
});
```

```css
.plot-line-icon {
  background-color: #FF0000;
  border-radius: 4px;
  width: 24px;
  height: 24px;
  fill: white;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/highcharts.js"></script>
<div id="container"></div>
```

In a bundler setup, you could also import svg paths like this:

```js
import { mdiImageLockOutline } from '@mdi/js'

const labelConfig = {
 text: `<svg viewBox="0 0 24 24" class="plot-line-icon"><path d="${mdiImageLockOutline}"></path></svg>`,
 useHTML: true,
}
```