# How to design a yAxis plotline with our own CSS?

Tags: highcharts

Already I have created a normal yAxis plotline with label styles.But now I want to create a yAxis plotline with some CSS styles. Any Suggestions?
This is what i have tried so far
[image]
This is my code

```
var chart = $('#tv_chart_container').highcharts();
chart.yAxis[0].removePlotLine('hori_line');
                          data = chart.series[0].data;
  var test = data.length;
  var value = data[999].y;
  chart.yAxis[0].addPlotLine({
  value: value, // Value of where the line will appear
  width: 2 ,  
  color: '#248EC6',
  // dashStyle: 'dash',
  id: 'hori_line',
  label: {
    text: value,
    align: 'right',
    style: {
      color: '#FFFFFF',
      fontWeight: 'bold',

    }
  }

  });
```

Here is the sample.What i actually need[image]

Comment: Some css styles? you may change color ,thickness etc   plotLines:[{
                value:450,
                color: '#ff0000',
                width:2,
                zIndex:4 
            }]

Comment: @NishithKantChaturvedi we currently did like that. But I need a plotline something like on the above image. See ath the end of the line there is a Pentagon shaped design which it contains yAxis value.

Comment: see this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15791918/highcharts-add-plotline-label-with-images

Comment: @Pilaventhiran If could please post a fiddle or code sample of what you've tried so far, I can see about working up an example based on your screenshot.

Comment: Hi, so you would like to achieve something similar to this chart? http://jsfiddle.net/3qfrke8t/2/

Answer (score 0):

I worked up a proof-of-concept that gets pretty close to what you're asking. This is using all code within Highcharts, and not anything dealing with outside CSS.

Plot lines can't possess the data label formatting you're seeking, so I used a scatter plot series to serve as the line instead. Plus, this also gives you the (default) Highcharts animation when you move over a new point in your line graph.

I did a few things here:

1. I added the scatter plot line as a separate "dummy" series that the user won't see in the legend and won't be able to interact with.
2. I formatted the data label for the last (second) point of the scatter plot line to show the blue background and white numerals as in your example.
3. I set a marker on the last (second) point of the scatter plot line with a diamond shape. Together with the data label settings, this gives you the marker example you showed above. Now, there is a `shape: 'callout'` option for data labels, but the carats only point up or down for this kind of series.
4. I updated your `mouseOver` event to update the value of the scatter plot line, rather than adding and removing plot lines.

Here's the proof-of-concept fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/brightmatrix/tzu3khp1/. You can also see a screenshot of the result below.

I hope all of this information is helpful for you. Please let me know if you have any questions; I'll be glad to update this answer to elaborate.

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your idea. But i cant use this with the yAxis plotlines.

Comment: @Pilaventhiran Why is that? This solution is meant to replace the plot lines, not work with them. Again, let me know if there's anything I can do to make this answer more helpful for you.

Comment: Because mine is a real time trading graph . So we have to update it for each and every second automatically without placing the cursor on graph